# Python BeautifulSoup How To Locate Span?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to locate a span on a HTML page, it isn't working. Can someone give me the code? Thank you alot.

`<div ng-repeat="m in messages" ng-if="hasMessage(m.message)" class="message-box success" ng-class="{ 'error': m.type == 'error', 'success': m.type == 'success', 'info': m.type == 'info', 'promotion': m.type == 'promotion' }"> <span ng-bind-html="m.message">Congratulations! Your $60 discount has been applied, enjoy $20 off your first 3 boxes.</span> <!----> </div>`

I tried this code

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
badges = soup.body.find('span', attrs={'class': 'message-box'})
for span in badges.span.find_all('span', recursive=False):
    print(span.attrs['title'])
```

I wanna get the $60 part.

Comment: post the code you have tried? not working means are you not getting output or is it throwing any error?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the sentence with BeautifulSoup, but to get the `$60` part you must use other techniques, for example `re` module:

```
txt = '''<div ng-repeat="m in messages" ng-if="hasMessage(m.message)" class="message-box success" ng-class="{ 'error': m.type == 'error', 'success': m.type == 'success', 'info': m.type == 'info', 'promotion': m.type == 'promotion' }"> <span ng-bind-html="m.message">Congratulations! Your $60 discount has been applied, enjoy $20 off your first 3 boxes.</span> <!----> </div>'''

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

text = soup.select_one('span[ng-bind-html="m.message"]').text

print( re.search(r'(\$\d+)', text).group(1) )
```

Prints:

```
$60
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @TrapStar The chance is that the page is populated by JavaScript, so what you see in the browser is not what the `BeautifulSoup` sees. Try to do `print(soup)` and check if the required tags are there.

Comment: It's not there :(

Comment: @TrapStar So you need to use `selenium` or other means to obtain that information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Andrej Kesely's answer will work. However, I think that you do not need to use regexes for a comparativevly simple operation. Remember:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

(Source: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

First of all, the reason that your original code didn't work was because of the `attrs` argument in this line:

```
soup.body.find('span', attrs={'class': 'message-box'})
```

When I ran the above line of code, it returned `None`. Why? I think the reason is like this: If you look at the original string, you will see that the span you want doesn't actually explictly have the  `message-box` class:

```
<span ng-bind-html="m.message">Congratulations! Your $60 discount has been applied, enjoy $20 off your first 3 boxes.</span>
```

I don't think BeautifulSoup is automatically smart enough to know that that the `span` inherited the `message-box` class from its parent `div`.

Anyway, here is the working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

original_string = """<div ng-repeat="m in messages" ng-if="hasMessage(m.message)" class="message-box success" ng-class="{ 'error': m.type == 'error', 'success': m.type == 'success', 'info': m.type == 'info', 'promotion': m.type == 'promotion' }"> <span ng-bind-html="m.message">Congratulations! Your $60 discount has been applied, enjoy $20 off your first 3 boxes.</span> <!----> </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(original_string)

# Use the span's explicitly declared 'ng-bind-html' attribute to find it
badges = soup.body.find('span', attrs={'ng-bind-html': 'm.message'})

# Note: the .get_text() method gets the actual text of the tag, with the surrounding html tags stripped away
# https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text
badges_text = badges.get_text()

dollar_amounts = []

# Use the "in" keyword to check for dollar signs, rather than regular expressions
# The .split method of a string splits the string into words
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split
for word in badges_text.split():
  if "$" in word:
    dollar_amounts.append(word)

# So you can see that it worked
# You can use list indexing to get the "$60" amount you said you wanted
# Remember: lists in python start from index 0
print(dollar_amounts[0])
```

Comment: badges_text = badges.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Can you give me the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: https://www.hellofresh.com/tasty/plans/tag/by_voucher/?c= (with a coupon)

Comment: When I visit the page, I immediately get confronted with a CAPTCHA

Comment: Oh, i dont get a captcha

Comment: When I try to access the page using requests, I get a 403 error (https://httpstatuses.com/403). The site clearly has measures in place to stop people doing this sort of thing (i.e. scraping)

Comment: Also, Selenium gets stopped by the CAPTCHA